# Refresh data in Django template without reloading page

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, django-templates

I'm trying to get new data added to DB without refresh the page. I'm using this library chartjs-plugin-streaming to live streaming data.

I've tried with a ajax callback to my URL in which my view is called
My view gets to my template my model.

view.py

```
def live(request):
queryset = Registro.objects.all()
if request.GET.get('ensayo__exact') is not None:
    queryset = queryset.filter(ensayo__exact=request.GET.get('ensayo__exact'))
if request.GET.get('presion') is not None:
    queryset = queryset.filter(presion=request.GET.get('presion'))
if request.GET.get('etapa') is not None:
    queryset = queryset.filter(etapa=request.GET.get('etapa'))
if request.GET.get('fecha__gte') is not None:
    queryset = queryset.filter(fecha__gte=request.GET.get('fecha__gte'))
if request.GET.get('fecha__lte') is not None:
    queryset = queryset.filter(fecha__lte=request.GET.get('fecha__lte'))

presion = [str(obj.presion) for obj in queryset]
etapa = [str(obj.etapa) for obj in queryset]
tempin = [str(obj.tempin) for obj in queryset]
fecha = [str(obj.fecha) for obj in queryset]
fecha__gte = [str(obj.fecha) for obj in queryset]
fecha__lte = [str(obj.fecha) for obj in queryset]
id = [int(obj.id) for obj in queryset]
ensayo_id = [int(obj.ensayo_id) for obj in queryset]

context = {
    'presion': json.dumps(presion),
    'etapa': json.dumps(etapa),
    'tempin': json.dumps(tempin),
    'fecha': json.dumps(fecha),
    'fecha__get': json.dumps(fecha),
    'fecha__lte': json.dumps(fecha),
    'id': json.dumps(id),
    'ensayo_id': json.dumps(ensayo_id)

}
return render(request, 'reporte/live_data.html', context)
```

and this are the js functions I've tried in my template and the canvas that render the li:

template.html

```
        function update() {
        $.get('', '', function() {
            return presion = JSON.parse('{{ presion|safe }}')
        });
    }

    function onRefresh(chart) {
        chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
            dataset.data.push({
                x: Date.now(),
                y: update(),
            });
        });
    }


    var color = Chart.helpers.color;
    var config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: fecha,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Presión (Bar)',
                backgroundColor: color(window.chartColors.blue).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
                borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                data: presion,
                fill: true,
            }]
        },
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Line chart (hotizontal scroll) sample'
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'realtime',
                    realtime: {
                        duration: 20000,
                        refresh: 1000,
                        delay: 2000,
                        onRefresh: onRefresh
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'value'
                    }
                }]
            },
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'nearest',
                intersect: false
            },
            hover: {
                mode: 'nearest',
                intersect: false
            }
        }
    };
```

Any idea or help?

Comment: what are you requesting in your `update` function?

Comment: I would like to go to URL that call to my view to get my page data update.!

Comment: Ok, but you are not requesting a URL there - the first parameter to `$.get` is an empty string? That function calls the URL in the first parameter and that URL must return the data which is displayed on the page. Do you have a route which just returns data rather than rendering the template?